# possible to change text size/color for ActionBar?

Tags: android, text, size, actionbarsherlock

Is there possible way to change size/color of ActionBar's title and subtitle?

I am using ActionBarSherlock for bridging between lower and higher versions. ActionBarSherlock provides way to customize text style in SherlockActionBarCompat, but there seems no way to make it in SherlockActionBarNative.

*edit:*
added by Jake and removed by author

*edit:*
Close to the solution:

```
<style name="resizeableTitleStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/action_bar_title_text_size</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.ResizeableActionBar" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/resizeableActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/resizeableActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">60dp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">60dp</item>
</style>

<style name="resizeableActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/resizeableTitleStyle</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/resizeableTitleStyle</item>
</style>
```

Thank Jake, the author of ABS, for the help.

Now it's almost done, except that the actionBarSize can only be estimated for an approximate absolute dimension(60dp for my app) from quite a few trials; wrap_content causes API2.2 to expand the whole screen and does API4.2.2 exception thrown while parsing xml.

**Addition**:
when actionBarSize set as 0dp, the output is as (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX4E1.png , low reputation to post images here directly): API2.2 in the left, the action bar occupies the whole screen without content, API4.2.2 in the right, content does without action bar.

when set as wrap_content, same output for API2.2, and exception thrown as: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x10

Comment: The `titleTextStyle` attributes go in a style that you reference from `actionBarStyle`.

Answer (score 9):

yes it is possible. You can do it through styles in this way:

```
<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/green_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/actionbar_textsize</item>
</style>
```

and use it with:

```
 <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
 <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
```

Comment: I replied in another post since it exceeds the comment's character restriction. please help

Comment: @Blackbelt:  Hi, can you explain why we need both "titleTextStyle" and "android:titleTextStyle" ? Thank you.

Comment: The answer is pretty old. Still, the one without android is/was for actionbarsherlock/actionbarcompat. The one with android is for the native actionbar @namanhams

Comment: Yea!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! good bad word bad word bad word. I was tinkering with this nonsense from last night right till now and never thought I had to define android text size right in the app theme style. Oh boy! Android api is the worst. I mean it makes Windows programming seem like abc. Atleast you can go onto MSDN for one hour tops and understand how to use a function. With android you have to spend the whole day searching android reference, which doesnt explain fully, then tutorials, stack over flow and back and forth like an investigative journalist until your luck comes true.

Comment: My other problem is Text View auto sizing. Everybody talks about autoSizeTextType auto min size and auto max size. But no good answers as to why it doesnt work for me at all. Not even Text View gravity fill works. I am guessing it has to do with an app theme attribute but that is just an hypothesis. I request assistance.

Comment: Better create a question with some code. Feel free to paste the link here