# Android How to change the size of the toolbar subtitle with XML attributes

Tags: android, styles, toolbar, subtitle

I am getting lost in trying to change the text size of the menu subtitle. There are many posts on the topic, however they refer to either action bar or toolbar. I don't have a "toolbar" in my MyMenu.xml but just "menu".
I have tried to replace the "menu" with "Toolbar" but then I receive a *Element android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar must be declared* and I am not sure I should get in such an important change as the app is working fine as it is.
I have tried also to modify actiobarstyle as in [possible to change text size/color for ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189877/possible-to-change-text-size-color-for-actionbar/16205463#16205463), but it does not work.
Thanks for your feedbacks

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/MyToobarSubtitleStyle">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        android:title="@string/P1MU_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/new_recipe"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="@string/P1MU_new"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:orderInCategory="1"/>
</menu>

 
styles.xml :
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bg_list</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyToobarSubtitleStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
        <item name="android:textSize">5dp</item>
    </style>
...
</resources>

layout of fragment:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recipe_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fdx.cookbook"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}```
````